# Get Text content of 3rd <p> element inside <div> element

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I have some HTML / JS code looking like this.

```js
    var bTags = document.getElementsByClassName("Wrapper");
    var kind = bTags[0];
    console.log(kind);
    console.log(kind.childNodes[4].text);
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}}</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In my example the "console.log(kind);" successfully logs the HTML object. Here its not working of course because its not defined. 
But somehow the childNodes[0-4].text is undefined. I just want to access the text of the p element with the class "placeDescription" of this specific parentNode.

Answer (score 2):

```
const el = document.querySelector('.Wrapper p:nth-of-type(3)');
if (el) {
 console.log(el.textContent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But If I have several of these HTML objects and thus several "Wrappers" it will not work ?!